# asp.net menu path

Tags: asp.net

How I get the Abslut path of asp menu in c#

Comment: Could you please include a bit more detail in your question as to what you are trying to do? As you question is right now, I would consider it to be unable to be answered

Comment: Item_menu.NavigateUrl gives me only part of the string. How can I get the absolute URL?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `MapPath` method. Like this:

```
var p = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Example.xml");
```